# How does wxpython exit Mainloop?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wxpython application, it runs this way:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainWindow("Application")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

there is an "exit" menu item on the application's menu bar, which binds:

```
def onExit(self, event):
    """"""
    self.Close()
```

- When "exit" is clicked, what happens exactly?
- When "exit" is clicked, what happens to app.MainLoop()?
- Is clicking "X" button on top-right of the frame window same with
  clicking "exit" button?
- Why doesn't python.exe*32 process end when I click "X" button, and
  how do I kill python.exe*32 process end when I click "X" button?
- Why wouldn't it print `"ok"` when I click "exit" if I run the script
  this way:

  ```
  if __name__ == "__main__":
      app = wx.App(False)
      frame = MainWindow("Application")
      frame.Show()
      app.MainLoop()
      print "ok"
  ```

Comment: Considering a few last bullets in your question: Does your app have tray icon by any chance? I remember having similar problem some time ago. Code similar to yours works for me on Windows 7, Python 2.7, wxPython 2.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When "exit" is clicked, what happens exactly?

   'exit' has an event binding to call the method onExit which calls the close method of this instance of MainWindow. This invokes an EVT_CLOSE event, you have the option to bind to this and control what happens, if you dont bind, it calls the Destroy method which destroys the window safely.
2. When "exit" is clicked, what happens to app.MainLoop()?

   The mainloop will continue processeing events unless the last of its top level windows is closed, when this happens the mainlop ends.
3. Is clicking "X" button on top-right of the frame window same with clicking "exit" button?

   Its kind of the same as it generates a EVT_CLOSE event which has a binding to onExit as above.
4. Why doesn't python.exe*32 process end when I click "X" button, and how do I kill python.exe*32 process end when I click "X" button?

   It should end when all top level windows are closed, you must still have a top level window in existance.
5. Why wouldn't it print "ok" when I click "exit" if I run the script this way

   Normally it would when there are no top level windows left.

Comment: The "exit" that the OP is talking about is a menu item. Menu items are bound to EVT_MENU, not EVT_CLOSE.

Comment: sorry i didn't mention EVT_MENU directly anywhere, i mentioned that exit has an event(which is the event EVT_MENU) that is bound to the onExit method, then it states that the onExit method invokes the EVT_CLOSE event(when the method Close is called).