# Stopping a wxPython loop

Tags: python, wxpython

I've been trying to stop a loop in wxPython and things I've been trying don't seem to work. I've tried using `self.app.ExitMainLoop()` and putting it in the `__init__` function, didn't work, tried putting it in the `varGUI` function, still didn't work. I could be doing this wrong and just being really stupid.

Here's the project I'm working on :

```
class varMenu(wx.Frame) :
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) :
        super(varMenu, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.varGUI()

    def varGUI (self) :
        global minVolAns
        global frameRateAns

        minVol = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "What is the minimum volume of the video?", "Minimum Volume",
                                     "Input Here")
        if minVol.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK :
            minVolAns=minVol.GetValue()

        frameRate = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "What framerate would you like?", "Framerate",
                                        "Input Here")
        if frameRate.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK :
            frameRateAns=frameRate.GetValue()


def main() :
    app = wx.App()
    varMenu(None, title = 'How would you like to edit your video?')
    app.MainLoop()

main()
```

For context, I want the program to continue after the questions so I can use the variable for my auto-cutter.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does wxpython exit Mainloop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659683/how-does-wxpython-exit-mainloop)

Comment: Thanks! It isn't exactly what I wanted but after a bit of editing, it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

After reading the answer of Rolf of Saxony, I realized that my own answer covers only half the problem in the question. So here is an updated answer.

***Updated Answer***

I guess the phrase at the end of the question, "*I want the program to continue after the questions*", refers to the fact that the code given does not show any window after the two `wx.TextEntryDialog` are shown and closed.

In this case, the program indeed continues to run after the two `wx.TextEntryDialog` are shown and closed. Even if nothing is shown after the two `wx.TextEntryDialog`, you can see in the terminal that the terminal prompt does not return, so the program is still running.

The reason for this behavior is two-fold.

1.- After finish using the two `wx.TextEntryDialog` you are not showing anything else. So the main loop of the program keeps runnig but has nothing to show. This can be fixed just by changing the main method in your code to:

```
def main() :
    app = wx.App()
    frame = varMenu(None, title = 'How would you like to edit your video?')
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Now the main window of your program is shown after the two `wx.TextEntryDialog` but if you close the main window the terminal prompt does not return meaning that your program is still running.

2.- The problem here is that you are creating an instance of `wx.TextEntryDialog` and then you are showing the instance with `ShowModal()` but you are not destroying the instance after finish using it. According to the docs of wxPython for `ShowModal()`:

> this function creates a temporary event loop which takes precedence
>   over the application’s main event loop (see wx.EventLoopBase) and
>   which is destroyed when the dialog is dismissed

For some `wx.Dialog` closing the window or pressing OK(Yes/No/Cancel) is enough to destroy the temporary event loop. For others, you need to call the `Destroy()` method to achieve this. Therefore, is better to make a habit of calling `Destroy()` after finish using a `wx.Dialog`. So your code must be modify to:

```
import wx

class varMenu(wx.Frame) :
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) :
        super(varMenu, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.varGUI()

    def varGUI (self) :
        global minVolAns
        global frameRateAns

        minVol = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "What is the minimum volume of the video?", "Minimum Volume",
                                     "Input Here")
        if minVol.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK :
            minVolAns=minVol.GetValue()
        minVol.Destroy()

        frameRate = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "What framerate would you like?", "Framerate",
                                        "Input Here")
        if frameRate.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK :
            frameRateAns=frameRate.GetValue()
        frameRate.Destroy()


def main() :
    app = wx.App()
    frame = varMenu(None, title = 'How would you like to edit your video?')
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

main()
```

Now when you finish using the two `wx.TextEntryDialog` and close the main window there is no loose temporary event loop and the program actually stop running.

***Original Answer:***

Welcome to StackOverflow

The main loop of your program continues. You can see in the terminal that the terminal prompt does not return after all the dialogs are shown because the main loop keeps running. The problem is that you are not showing anything except the dialogs.

Just change the `main` method to:

```
def main() :
    app = wx.App()
    frame = varMenu(None, title = 'How would you like to edit your video?')
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

and you will see the main window after the dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

You have failed to `Destroy` both of your dialogs, which is why the program is not closing.
Try this:

```
import wx

class varMenu(wx.Frame) :
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) :
        super(varMenu, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, value="Your Main Screen")
        self.minVolAns = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, value="")
        self.frameRateAns = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, value="")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.textCtrl,0,wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.minVolAns)
        sizer.Add(self.frameRateAns)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.varGUI()
        self.Show()

    def varGUI(self):
        minVol = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "What is the minimum volume of the video?", "Minimum Volume","")
        if minVol.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK :
            self.minVolAns.SetValue(minVol.GetValue())
        minVol.Destroy()

        frameRate = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "What framerate would you like?", "Framerate","")
        if frameRate.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK :
            self.frameRateAns.SetValue(frameRate.GetValue())
        frameRate.Destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = varMenu(None, title = 'How would you like to edit your video?')
    app.MainLoop()
```